# Sensible/correct way to edit the files provided by base-files package?

Tags: configuration, etc, editing

I understand the package `base-files` provides the *Debian base system miscellaneous files*    such as /etc/issue, /etc/lsb-release (in the specific case of Ubuntu) or /etc/os-release.

I'd like to know what is the most sensible way or the correct way to edit these files, would simply edit them via `nano` or a graphical text editor do the job?.

(I'm aware that as I edit those files they will be overridden once the package is updated).

Comment: is this opinion-based question?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it. No, I'm asking what is the correct way to edit those files.

Comment: Why would you want to edit them?

Comment: @Braiam curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I never got an answer, I'll answer it myself.

Editing the files that the package `base-files` provides with any text editor works, be it with `nano` or Gedit.